# GMLib move existing marker

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe7, gmlib

Using GMLib on Delphi XE-7, I'm trying to move existing marker to new position, I have created only one marker on the map and tried using code below as a test to move it.

```
procedure TfrmMapClient.GMMap1Click(Sender: TObject; LatLng: TLatLng; X, Y:   Double);
begin

mcnt := gmmarker1.count;
gmmarker1.Items[0].Position:= LatLng;

end;
```

but getting Exception Access Violation.
Any help much appreciated

Comment: try using Assign method

Comment: how do I do that? can you give a sample. been trying todo this the whole day without success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with

```
gmmarker1.Items[0].Position.Assign(LatLng);
```

or assigning individual properties

```
gmmarker1.Items[0].Position.Lat := LatLng.Lat;
gmmarker1.Items[0].Position.Lng := LatLng.Lng;
```